# iscroll issue with two dimensional ( horizontal + vertical ) scrolling, scrollable are related issue?

Tags: javascript, scroll, mobile-website, iscroll4

**Problem in brief**

I have got a piece of working two dimensional scrolling code. Scrolling as such is working fine. Scrolling can be done in any direction (not like restricted to only horizontal or only vertical at a ti,e) but there are two problems -

- Scrolling beyond the visible area towards top and left, does not bounce back the scrollable area.
- Scrolling to right and bottom bounces back.

Problem demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepan_nits/pAhjU/6/
*Note -* Test in webkit browsers only (Google chrome and Safari).

**Solution I am looking for**

- Either, point out what is wrong in my code.
- Or share any properly implemented working demo of both ways scroll (horizontal + vertical) using the same version of iscroll, so that I can follow the same. I am using - version 3.7.1, preferable, or using iscroll version 4, fine as well.
- Or any pointers, of course, would be appreciated.

**Problem Description**

Please check working code here - http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepan_nits/pAhjU/6/

*Note -*

- Test in webkit browsers only (Google chrome and Safari).
- I have knowingly put everything inside the HTML section in the jsfiddle, because if I separate things completely, the scrolling does not work, and I am not sure where exactly it stops working. Thanks if you can point out.

**Code**

Here is the HTML -

```
<div class="header">
    <div class='left_link'></div>Demo</div>
    <div id="main_content" class="main_content">

    <b><div id=scroller1><br/> 
    <div class='center_data'>Scrollable area</div>
    <div class='center_data'>hello world!</div>
    <br/> 
    </div></b>

</div>
```

**Note -** I know there is invalid html there - `<div id=scroller1>` is inside `<b></b>` and I am not sure why if I remove the `<b></b>` tags, horizontal scrolling does not work anymore - [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepan_nits/pAhjU/12/).

Here is the js -

```
    var myScroll;
    var a = 0;
    function loaded() {
        //setHeight();  // Set the wrapper height. Not strictly needed, see setHeight() function below.

        // Please note that the following is the only line needed by iScroll to work. Everything else here is to make this demo fancier.
        myScroll = new iScroll('scroller1', {desktopCompatibility:true});
        //myScroll2 = new iScroll('scroller2', {desktopCompatibility:true});

    }


    // Prevent the whole screen to scroll when dragging elements outside of the scroller (ie:header/footer).
    // If you want to use iScroll in a portion of the screen and still be able to use the native scrolling, do *not* preventDefault on touchmove.
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

    // Load iScroll when DOM content is ready.
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

I guess the reason is that the scrollable div is by default rendered at the bottom-right corner of the scrollable area. But I am not sure about the proper way to configure those things - how to set where to render the scrollable div inside the scollable area. So far I did not find any working demo of both ways scrolling - horizontal + vertical scrolling.

I checked out the [documentation of iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) and many working demos, but did not find any demo where scrolling can be done both ways - horizontally as well as vertically. I checked the "Accepted options are:" section under "Syntax" section in http://cubiq.org/iscroll but none of those params seem to be what I am exactly looking for.

**Other things**

- Also, one more thing, I am not able to view the area covered by dom elements in chrome browser, while I inspect the given scroll demo. By viewing the area I mean moving the mouse over the dom inspector panel highlights the dom in the browser view. When does it not appear? I checked with validated HTML as in http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepan_nits/pAhjU/12/.
- Somebody please create a tag `iscroll` or `iscroll3` so that I can retag my question.

**Update**
I just want to have normal two dimensional scrolling with the scroll area being properly inside the visible screen and there should be bounce back on taking outside the screen. Right now there is no bounce back (in my jsfiddle) on scrolling towards top and left, outside screen. Bounce back happens on scrolling to right and bottom. I just want the scrolling area to be well placed inside the screen. I guess bounce back will automatically get fixed then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [last version (4.1.8)](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) on the github repo will fix your problem ;) I'm using it on some projects and it is now optimized for desktop browser ;)

**Edit**

From the documentation :

```
hScroll, used to disable the horizontal scrolling no matter what. By default you can pan both horizontally and vertically, by setting this parameter to false you may prevent horizontal scroll even if contents exceed the wrapper.
vScroll, same as above for vertical scroll.
```

By default, when creating a new iScroll('idOfElement') the scroll is vertical and horizontal. It can be disabled with these parameters. Dual Scroll is totally possible as [this video](http://vimeo.com/20475917) shows it.

So, to force dual Scroll :

```
var myScroller = new iScroll('idOfElement', {vScroll:true, hScroll:true});
```

Comment: Where can I see a working demo of 2D scroll (horizontal + vertical) using this version? I searched for that earlier but could not find.

Comment: I had checked that previously. Now checked again but all the demos I saw are either vertical-only scroll (like http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/custom-scrollbar/) or horizontal-only scroll (like http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/carousel/). Am I missing the 2D demo somewhere?

Comment: This information is spot on thank you so much. The project documentation really is lacking some of these nuance features, still an amazing script though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but this might help you.

First of all, The HTML code was not properly nested, and so you were needed to put the `<div>` inside the `<b>`. I fixed up the HTML a bit and its working without the `<b>`

http://jsfiddle.net/Aexhz/

And with properly nested HTML and correct settings, This worked even after dividing the HTML/JS/CSS

For me, it does show some Horizontal as well as Vertical Scrolling, but i don't know if that's how you want it to be. i Edited the Class initialization line as well

```
    myScroll = new iScroll('scroller1', {desktopCompatibility:true});
```

TO

```
myScroll = new iScroll('scroller1', {
    snap: true,
    momentum: false,
    hScrollbar: false,
    vScrollbar: false,
    desktopCompatibility: true
});
```

This doesn't affects much but i still put that.

I will continue looking into this and update my answer if i find anything new.

Comment: first of all thanks for trying... I have updated the question title too... I think that was confusing. I checked the scrolling in your jsfiddle. Looks like scrolling in horizontal direction has reduced now (moving only little bit). Please check my update

Comment: scrolling has to be just like we move the mouse pointer in the screen

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to fix this using iscorll but wanted to share this with you, i had great results using it: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#usage

It is highly customizable with css, a demo here with vertical and horizontal scroll: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html